# Distribution of a matrix product $\mathbf{a}^{H}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{b}$

Tags: matrices, random-variables, matrix-calculus, random-matrices

Could someone help prove the following:
I have two independent random vectors $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$. Both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ have unit norm. There is a matrix $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$. Every element of $\mathbf{H}$ is  an i.i.d. complex Gaussian random variable with zero mean and unit variance. Could someone show why $\mathbf{a}^{H}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{b}$ is a comlex gaussian variable with unit variance?

Thinks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an approach that seems to work. Write $a$ and $b$ as products of random unitary matrices $U_a \in U(M)$ $U_b \in U(N)$ with uniform (Haar) measure on the unitary group and $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots)$.
$$
a = U_a e_1
$$
$$
b = U_b e_1
$$

Now the product you want is:
$$
a^H Hb = e_1^TU_a^HH U_b e_1
$$
$H$ is a random unitary matrix with Gaussian measure $\propto \exp(-||H ||_F^2)$. This measure is invariant under left and right unitary transformations and therefore $U_a^HH U_b$ has the same distribution as $H$. As a result, your product is equivalent to any entry in $H$: a complex Gaussian w/ zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: Hi D.A.N, I think it is correct to use the fact that $U_a^HH U_b$ has the same distribution as $H$. Thanks so much for the answer. I have another question: what if the matrix $H$ is a matrix with iid Gaussian elements only on the diagonal. Is $\mathbf{a}^{H}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{b}$ still a complex Gaussian variable?

Comment: No problem, I find these types of problems to be fun.  The same argument doesn't hold for diagonal case, and I'm not confident you will get a gaussian as the result. For $M=N$, it's pretty easy to compute the expected mean to be 0, and variance to be $(1+i)/N$, so clearly it's not a Gaussian with unit variance, but it could still be Gaussian. Let me know if you do find a solution!